# Bool tool difference not working

Tags: modifiers

I'm new to Blender following a tutorial by Josh Gambrell, I have created a main object ("Cube"), using a cube but remove the upside vertices and left plane like object, then solidify.

I then try to make a cut using 'Cube.006' with  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>Numpad minus (-)</kbd>  of booltool, but this seem not to work. I have done some cut before with this method (I create collection cutter),and it works.
Not sure what caused this.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You bevel doesn't work well with the cutter because there are overlapping edges.

[image: Overlapping edges with bevel]

You could just lower the bevel amount from 0.1 m to 0.09 m. This pulls the bevel back enough to avoid overlapping edges.

[image: Working cutter]

Another option would be to move the problematic boolean modifier above the first bevel modifier. This way the boolean would work better but you would need to adjust the bevel modifier more to get as deep bevel.

### Extra:

Also remember to give your cutters smooth shading and auto smooth to get cleaner holes.

[image: Clean hole]

Comment: Thanks Joonas the cutter is work now, but regard the smooth shading, i have done  'shade smooth' and also have my auto smooth ticked (in object data properties), but no change happen

Comment: You are welcome. You have to Shade Smooth and Auto Smooth all your cutters. This means the Cylinders and Cubes you are using to cut parts away from your main object. Also if the answer was useful then you can accept the answer by clicking the check mark next to the answer.

Comment: Yes, It works now, It seem I incorrectly activate the object last time, I should activate the cutter for shade smooth, thank you.